# Poor Image Quality on scaling image in android

Tags: android, imageview

I am working on android application development...when i click on thumbnail image, it enlarges but give extreme poor quality...please help me how to resolve it

```
ImageView ivPreview = (ImageView)nagDialog.findViewById(R.id.image1);

int h =200 ; // height in pixels
int w = 200; // width in pixels    
Bitmap Scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, h, w, true);

ivPreview.setImageBitmap(Scaled);
```

Comment: int h =200 ; // height in pixels
int w = 200; // width in pixels this should removed from your code and the original height and width of image should be passed to Bitmap

Comment: the quality goes away because you are forcefully compressing image to 200 x 200 and due to which the original image which may be 800 x 480 gets saturated

Comment: BitmapDrawable bd=(BitmapDrawable) this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image);
int height=bd.getBitmap().getHeight();
int width=bd.getBitmap().getWidth();

Comment: use the code it may help you :)

Comment: it's not working....first what i have to do is that i have to convert image in a small thumbnail....and save in a listbox. then i have to enlarge when user clicks it..

Comment: when you click on thumbnail redirect the click to original image and give the original image size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to enlarge a thumbnail. This is a bad idea because a thumbnails' size is a small image and enhancing it only makes it look worse. The Bitmap.createScaledBitmap() method stretches the bitmap resulting in quality loss. You should use a bigger original image, create the thubmnail from that image and load the original image when you click on it. Here's some code to get you going:

```
  Bitmap original = //get original image
  Bitmap thumbnail = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(original, 50, 50, true);

  //when the user clicks on the imageview:
  imgView.setImageBitmap(original);
```